# Pass variable to jquery modal dialog open function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show a jquery modal dialog box on error of two fetch methods. The modal dialogs are same except for the body in open function. I would like to create only a single function and pass the body text as parameters from the fetch methods. How can I do the same?

```
const fetchCallOne = () => {
  try {
  } catch(err) {
    alertForDialogFetchCallOne.dialog('open');
  }
}

const fetchCallTwo = () => {
  try {
  } catch(err) {
    alertForDialogFetchCallTwo.dialog('open');
  }
}

const alertForDialogFetchCallTOne = $('<div></div>').dialog({
  title: 'Note',
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  open: function() {
    $(this).html('Fetch Call One Error');
  },
  buttons: {
    Ok: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    },
  },
});

const alertForDialogFetchCallTwo = $('<div></div>').dialog({
  title: 'Note',
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  open: function() {
    $(this).html('Fetch Call Two Error');
  },
  buttons: {
    Ok: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    },
  },
});
```

As seen above the only difference is the `body` of `open`. So how can I make only one function and call it with parameters?

For eg:

```
alertForDialogAnyFetchCall.dialog('open').body('Fetch Call One Error');
alertForDialogAnyFetchCall.dialog('open').body('Fetch Call Two Error');
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is what you looking for

```js
function message(type){
alert(type);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick=message("open")> Click me </button>
```